# How to remove ' ' from my list python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.2

```
newlist=['21', '6', '13', '6', '11', '5', '6', '10', '11', '11', '21', '17', '23', '10', '36', '4', '4', '7', '23', '6', '12', '2', '7', '5', '14', '3', '10', '5', '9', '43', '38']
```

Now what I want to do with this list is take out the ' ' surrounding each integer, the problem is that the split() function or the strip() function wont work. So I don't know how to remove it. Help.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' is given when I run.

Also After that I want to find the sum of each 7 integers in the list, and that I also don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide your [mcve]

Comment: There are no single quotes in your list. You don't have a list of integers, but of strings... Are you asking how to make them ints?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of strings (hence the ''s), and you want to convert them to integers. The boring solution to the problem is a simple for loop:

```
for i in range(len(newlist)):
    newlist[i] = int(newlist[i]
```

The more compact method is a list comprehension, which you can read about here: [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newlist = [int(num) for num in newlist]
```

The two functions you mentioned operate only on single strings.

```
>>> "Hi my name is Bob".split(" ")
["Hi", "my", "name", "is", "Bob"]
```

```
>>> "GARBAGE This string is surrounded by GARBAGE".strip("GARBAGE")
" This string is surrounded by "
```

As @Tomoko Sakurayama mentioned, you can sum simply enough with another loop. If you're feeling fancy, though, you can use another list comprehension (or even stack it on the old one, though that's not very Pythonic :).

```
[sum(newlist[i:i+7]) for i in range(0, len(newlist) - 6, 7)] + [sum(newlist[-(len(newlist) % 7):])]
```

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't work because it is a list of strings rather than integers.

```
 x = [int(x) for x in newlist]
```

This will cast every value in the list to be an int.

> Also After that I want to find the sum of each 7 integers in the list

^ Can you clarify what this means? Is this the sum of every seven consecutive numbers until the end of the list? If so,

```
sums = []
index = 0
for i in range(0, len(newlist), 7):
    sums[index] = sum(newlist[i : i + 7)])
    index += 1
```

EDIT:
Full code:

```
x = [int(x) for x in newlist]
sums = []
for i in range(0, len(x), 7):
    sums.append(sum(x[i : i + 7]))
```

Comment: It says an error that you cant assign to function call for  x = [x for int(x) in newlist]

Comment: sums[index] = sum(newlist[i : i + 7])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That's because `newlist` still contains strings. And once the `TypeError` is fixed, you will see an `IndexError` instead...

Comment: @alaniwi So how do I fix this

Comment: How long is your list of ints? It might be because it is not divisible by seven, so it tries to access indices that are out of bounds

Comment: @Wafinator Well if you use the `x` that was the result of converting to ints, instead of `newlist`, the `sum` will work. But @TomokoSakurayama's loop is trying to append to a list by assigning to the next index off the end of the list, and that is going to raise an `IndexError`. The way to append to a list is to use its `append` method.

Comment: @TomokoSakurayama Its 31, so yeah its not divisible by 7, so How can I find the sum of the remaining integers left?

Comment: @Wafinator The "remaining integers left" part is okay. A slice like `[i : i + 7]` will contain a _maximum_ of 7 elements, but it could be fewer if it finds the end of the list.

Comment: @alaniwi I mean Im still getting the error saying its all strings even though he made it into integers and put it under the value x, how can I replace x with newlist in the code. Does that even fix it?

Comment: @Wafinator If you followed this answer, you didn't make it into integers. You evaluated an expression that converted it into integers, and assigned this to a different variable, called `x`. The contents of `newlist` itself will not be changed by doing this.

Comment: @alaniwi ok I think I fixed that part, now im getting that IndexError: list assignment index out of range error that you mentioned.

Comment: Get rid of all the bits involving `index` and use `sums.append(sum(x[i : i + 7)]))` instead....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for python's [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
oldlist = ['21', '6', '13', '6', '11', '5', '6', '10', '11', '11', '21', '17', '23', '10', '36', '4', '4', '7', '23', '6', '12', '2', '7', '5', '14', '3', '10', '5', '9', '43', '38']
newlist = list(map(int, oldlist))

print(type(newlist[0]))
print(newlist)
```

And output:

```
<class 'int'>

[21, 6, 13, 6, 11, 5, 6, 10, 11, 11, 21, 17, 23, 10, 36, 4, 4, 7, 23, 6, 12, 2, 7, 5, 14, 3, 10, 5, 9, 43, 38]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map for this case;

```
new_list = list(map(int, newlist))

print(new_list) == [21, 6, 13, 6, 11, 5, 6, 10, 11, 11, 21, 17, 23, 10, 36, 4, 4, 7, 23, 6, 12, 2, 7, 5, 14, 3, 10, 5, 9, 43, 38]
```